# Watin Tests fail on CC.Net

Tags: unit-testing, watin, xunit.net

I'm running Watin tests with xUnit on CC.Net under Windows Server 2003.

I have lots of tests that all run fine on development boxes with TestDriven.Net and on the server with the xUnit gui app. However, when CC.Net runs the tests (as part of an MSBuild task) the function

```
ie.ContainsText("some text to find");
```

never returns the expected value. Other functions and properties on the IE object appear to work fine: Button(...).Click(), TextBox(...).Value, etc.

I am aware that the service account needs "Allow service to interact with the desktop".

I have tried this running CC service under Local System and local Administrator. The administrator account just hangs and never appears to finish running the tests (though it does create an instance of the iexplorer.exe process.

Is this an issue with permissioning on the server, or have I left something out of the configuration?

Comment: When I need to keep an active session on a machine I've been using Caffeine: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/Caffeine.shtml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We just finished figuring out how to work around this problem.  We now have watin tests running through CruiseControl.net running as a service.

We need our cc.net service to run as a specific user in order to access the website we are testing due to the way the security is set up.  Since the service is running as a domain user the 'Allow user to interact with desktop' checkbox is disabled on the service security tab.  We don't want to just run the command process from an always logged in user because we want the process to start automatically on reboot.  Now we have figured out

The way we worked around this was by first creating a batch file to call the nunit-console.exe.  Parameters to nunit-console.exe are passed to the batch file as parameters which then passes the parameters on. The second, and last, line of the batch file returns the return code returned from nunit-console.exe.  The batch file essentially looks like this:

```
 nunit-console.exe %1 %2
 exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The number of parameters you pass through to nunit-console may be different based on your needs.

We are using nant for our builds, so then we replaced our existing nant task to call nunit-console with an exec task that calls cmd.exe that looks like this:

```
   <exec program="cmd.exe" failonerror="true">
      <arg value="/interactive" />
      <arg value="/c" />
      <arg value="[batch file name]" />
      <arg value="[parameter one value]" />
      <arg value="[parameter two value" />
   </exec>
```

I don't know what the same task would look like in msbuild but I'm sure you can look it up.  The ultimate result is essentially a command that looks like this:

```
   cmd.exe /interactive /c [batch file name] [parameter one value] [parameter two value]
```

Alternatively, you could use nant and just create msbuld nant tasks to call your existing builds.

The '/interactive' parameter to cmd.exe is the key, it runs the batch file on a process that has permission to interact with the desktop. I'm actually not positive if the '/c' parameter is required, but it is working as it is.  We are still telling nunit to log the results to the same xml file so our merge task didn't need to change and the reporting of the test results to cruise control is working great.

Comment: Brilliant! Created a batch file to call msbuild with just the Test target (/t:Test) and executed it using an exec task from ccnet. All the other targets are still running on an msbuild for simplicity. Works like charm.

Comment: it doesn't work when you need to handle IE window, like alert message, or file download window. I am still looking for a way to solve this.

Comment: Not sure exactly which commands you are having a problem with.  We haven't run into any problems yet and we've been running WatIn on ccnet this way for a while.  I suspect that the problem you are talking about is not specific to my solution but would be a problem running WatIn unattended by any method.

Answer (score 1):

Watin relies on browser automation to do it's job, thus the "allow service to interact with desktop" setting.

When Watin tries to run it will do so under the service account not the desktop that's currently logged in, and since it's going to spin up IE it's possible that the account you're running Watin under hasn't actually started IE itself before and it could be sitting in the initial startup sequence for IE where it prompts for settings and all that hoo-hah.

Also, if I recall correctly, the interact with desktop setting requires an active login to interact with.  If no one is logged in at the time there's going to be nothing for the service to talk to and it's not going to create a new desktop for you.

Comment: Hence my problem. Whether using the service, or running manually, an active session must be maintained on the integration server. Is there no way around this?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've received a couple of suggestions offline:

1. Attempt running the tests with msbuild on the server.
2. Try starting CC.Net from the console instead of as a service.

Will edit with results.

**EDIT:**

Results:

1. I am fully able to run the tests with msbuild on the server.
2. When I run ccnet.exe from the command line the tests run fine. However, when I setup a task to start ccnet.exe from the command line on startup, the tests hang and never finish (eventually timing out).

Partial workaround is to run the command line executable on a session that never dies. I really don't like this solution though, so any further input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that answer was marked correct with an invalid exec example..

I rewrote it to:

`<exec>
<baseDirectory>WatinTestDir</baseDirectory>
<executable>cmd.exe</executable>
<buildArgs>/interactive /C nunit-launcher.bat Test.dll /xml:../Test-results.xml</buildArgs>
<buildTimeoutSeconds>2400</buildTimeoutSeconds>
</exec>`

Which runs.. but fails all the same..

Comment: The example is not invalid.  What you have listed is a CCNet exec task.  What is listed in the example is a nAnt exec task, as was stated in the answer.  If you are having problems writing CCNet exec tasks I'm sure you could open another question and someone would answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this example, but it did not help me, sadly. Since this question is about nant, and I use msbuild, I've opened up a separate question for this [at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652107/selenium-times-out-when-run-in-ccnet-as-a-service).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution but does not solve the problem is you are trying to download files using Watin.

http://blog.kikicode.com/2011/10/run-minimized-batch-file-in-task.html

This worked for me. The issue was that the cmd prompt was blocking IE from coming up. When I was able to minimize the cmd prompt it allowed IE to gain focus and download the files I needed in my process.