# Watin from TeamCity not running as a Windows Service

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, watin, webtest

I'm trying to run Watin from within a TeamCity build, using nUnit.

All tests run fine locally. I know you cannot run the full Watin tests (i.e. POST) from TeamCity if it is running as a Windows Service. You must start the build agent from a .bat file.

But, I don't want to have to login to the server for it to start.

I've tried getting a Scheduled Task (in Windows Server 2008) to fire the agent.bat file on StartUp (not Login), but with no luck.

Has anyone else got Watin/TeamCity running from a Scheduled Task?

Thanks,

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the solution to doing this using CC.NET.

[Watin Tests fail on CC.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640273/watin-tests-fail-on-cc-net/1241329#1241329)

Brett and I worked on this for awhile.  The problem is that Windows Services running as a user cannot interact with the desktop, but because WatiN runs a real instance of the browser it requires a desktop to interact with.  The solution in the link provided can show you how to do this.

Comment: I still have problem to handle file download window for example. The window is never shown, so WatiN cannot handle it.

Comment: Yea, never dealt with a file download window, though we did have file upload windows which work just fine using the approach I linked.