# Running WatiN using Scheduled task or Windows service

Tags: scheduled-tasks, watin

My WatiN automation for doing file download is working fine when executed in command window normally. But failing with timeout exceptions or fileDownload Dialog not found exception when executed as a scheduled task.

Is it possible to execute WatiN exe (with filedownload dialog handler) as a scheduled task. If NO is there any other way to execute it as a schedule task.

Note: I have seen some blogs referring to running WatiN using cc.net. So, is it possible to run above scenario using cc.net Any pointers for cc.ent documentation and its working

Let me know if u require any more informations..

Answer (score 1):

Check out the solution to doing this using CC.NET.

[Watin Tests fail on CC.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640273/watin-tests-fail-on-cc-net/1241329#1241329)

Brett and I worked on this for awhile. The problem is that Windows Services running as a user cannot interact with the desktop, but because WatiN runs a real instance of the browser it requires a desktop to interact with. The solution in the link provided can show you how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

i had a problem with windows scheduler so i just switched to "smooth program scheduler" and it just worked