# Open web page, login and then download file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, automation, watin

Task: I have to open a web page (https), enter username and password, click some links to get to a desired page and then download all files (pdf) to a shared folder on our internal network.

I'd like to do this with windows service which would run once every night. What is the best way to do this?

I tried [watin](http://watin.org/), it is pretty easy to fire up a browser, navigate to my web page, enter username and password, click some links, ... but then I don't know how to automatically download a file. As I understand, you can't do this without user interaction. Also - I don't know if it is even possible to run watin from windows service; where would the browser instance be running?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Well I don't know exactly how services work but I've run a couple of tests through test agent ( which I believe is a service ), so there's no concern there. Depending on you OS there are ways to download the file - if it's Win7 it's a bit difficult, but possible.

Comment: If you own the website are you able to write a wcf service for example and use that to provide mechanism to access to the data you want?

Comment: @Bronumski - no such luck, it's not my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can do the following:*

1. Save the page with entered username and password in it
2. Write a small `C#` client program that will run a local server which
   will submit the page file
3. Gaining the session, submit also a previously saved `URL` to the `PDF`
   downloadable page
4. In the same app add the client downloading part that downloads all
   the files existing under that `session`.

*Writing such a program wont take more than an hour from your time.*

**Advantages:**

1. You can change over time, the way you like it to perform
2. You have full control on your client part

Answer (score 1):

Why not just login with watiN, then loop through the browser.links collection downloading the files with a normal c sharp web request?
 Re as a service see [Running WatiN using Scheduled task or Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719047/running-watin-using-scheduled-task-or-windows-service)